# Javascript Object and Classes

Tags: javascript

I have a code snippet of JavaScript:

```
mf.profile.push({
 "Site": {
   "Name": "Jack Montana",                  
   "Identity": 61026032,                   
   "Email": "jack@gmail.com",               
   "Phone": "+14155551234",                
   "Gender": "M",                          
  }
});

mf.event.push("Product viewed", {
    "Product name": "Casio Chronograph Watch",
    "Category": "Mens Accessories",
    "Price": 59.99,
    "Date": new Date()
});
```

Now my question is what does `mf.profile.push` or `mf.event.push` signify?

Is `mf` an object and `profile` a function? or both are classes and `push` is a function?

Comment: All we can say for sure is that `mf` is an object, that `mf.profile` and `mf.event` are objects and that `mf.profile.push` and `mf.profile.push` are functions. However, *any value that is not a primitive value* is an object. Arrays are objects and so are functions. Any of the values that I identifier as "objects" could also be arrays or functions.

Answer (score 4):

> what does mf.profile.push or mf.event.push signify

The `mf` variable is an Object literal and the `profile/event` are properties (may of type `array`) belongs to this object.

The **[`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** is a method that will add the items passed as parameters to those attributes.

Comment: You can't really know whether they are arrays. They could be arbitrary objects.

Comment: `.push` is a *method*, not a function.

Comment: @user3539626 if the answer is what you're looking for Mark it as the **[correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** for the future readers.

Comment: @vlaz all methods are functions... anyway thanks for your intervention, updated my post...

Comment: A method belongs to a class, while functions are not associated with one. So `student.doHomework()` is a method and `doHomework(student)` is a function. In JS it happens that all procedures are called functions, so the definition of a method via JS lingo would be property of an object that contains a function definition. However, that shouldn't stop us using correct terminology, for even a property of an object containing a function is still a method. Were we to go that way, then Java wouldn't have any FP paradigms, as there are no functions, just classes with methods.

Comment: @FelixKling the most chance of the properties is being an array. `push()` method is used mostly (or perhaps only) on arrays.